# How to create a stored procedure that generates a CSV file from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to generate a `.CSV` file based on data in a datatable. I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find any examples of how to specify what the separator should be.

For example if I have a table and a query like this, this is what I want the output to be:

MyTable:

```
Id - Int Key
NickName- NvarChar
REALName - NvarChar
Number - NvarChar
Updated - bit
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Updated = 1
```

Output:

I want my output to use `|` as the field separator. So the output in the CSV file will look something like this:

```
Id|NickName|REALName|Number|Updated
1|NickNameHere|RealNameHere|0798548558|1
2|NickNameHere2|RealNameHere2|079948558|1
```

and so on.

Comment: Are you using 3 different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Use BCP to create the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

The following query generate CSV data with '|' separator

```
select 'Id|NickName|REALName|Number|Updated'
union all
select
       cast (Id as nvarchar) + '|'
       + NickName  + '|'
       + RealNameHere  + '|'
       + Number + '|'
       + cast (Updated as nvarchar)
    from MyTable 
    WHERE Updated = 1
```

Saving output results to TextFile:

**Method 1**: from within SSMS

From ssms menu: query -> results to -> results to file

**Method 2**: using Powershell [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683370.aspx)

```
 Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "your query" | Export-Csv "path\to\csvfile"
```

**Method 3**: using [SqlCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) command line tool:

```
sqlcmd -q "your query" -o "path\to\csvfile" -S server -P password -d database
```

Comment: but how do I get that to output/create a CSV file, surely this is just the select.